# I have a hunch about ten of the high reach accounts here are the same person

Tags: discussion

I have a hunch about ten of the high reach accounts here are the same person. Am I right? They must be quite the polymath anyway, if so.

Comment: Nope, or they are also an IT specialist with 9 VPNs that are *always* linked to the same accounts.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking [You could be in on it.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/)

Answer (score 2):

Curiously, it sounds like solipsism of sorts. There's just you and the bots on the Internet. You'll be happy to know that I, I mean we, have been noticed by the Internet writ large. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Internet_theory for more information.

If it helps, I vouch for my rabel-rousing existence independent of the moderators whom I hold in high esteem despite my penchant for prior rambling exhortations.